# ContextMenu integration with FullCalendar 4.0

Tags: fullcalendar

Context menu integration is not available in fullcalendar 4.0, the same can be achieved easily in versions with eventrender and jquery.ui-contextmenu.min.js file.
But the jquery element is not available in full calendar 4.0 I am facing issues to get the similar functionality.

Comment: Just wrap the DOM element you are given by fullCalendar inside a jQuery element, just as you would any other DOM element if you wanted to use it with jQuery. e.g. `$(info.el)` or similar

Comment: See https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-element for documentation

Comment: $('#calendar').contextmenu({
    delegate: '.fc-event',
    menu: [{
      title: 'Clone Cell',
      cmd: 'cloneCell'
    }],select: function(event, ui) {
      var someEvents = calendar.getEvents().filter(function(event) {
     return event.title === ui.target.text();
   }); if(ui.cmd == 'cloneCell'){ $.ajax({type: "POST",url: '' })} }});

Comment: Thank you @Adyson, Initially I tried with info.el html element, but not successfull, then I use one of the available class '.fc-event' as the value for delegate, please check the code. <script src="/jquery.ui-contextmenu.min.js"></script>, $('#calendar').new fullCalendar(); //calendardiv
$('#calendar').contextmenu({ delegate: '.fc-event', menu: [{ title: 'Clone Cell', cmd: 'cloneCell' }],select: function(event, ui) { var someEvents = calendar.getEvents().filter(function(event) { return event.title === ui.target.text(); }); if(ui.cmd == 'cloneCell'){ $.ajax({type: "POST",url: '' })} }});

Comment: Please don't paste code in the comments - as you can see yourself, it's unreadable and not very useful. If you found a working solution please write an Answer below. If you didn't find a solution but want to show more code then please edit your question and update it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, in fullcalendar 4.0, no support for element, so I added 'class' as the extendedProps for the event object, then added context menu based on this class name but unable to send the event id details when I click on context menu on that specific event as I can only get the event title(that is what is showing on the UI target), how to get the ID of that particular event as like in full calendar 3.0(element.attr('data-event-id', event.id);), please suggest.

Comment: See my previous comment. If you need to add more information, please **edit your question**. There is an "edit" button just underneath the blue "fullCalendar" tag.

Comment: "in fullcalendar 4.0, no support for element"...no idea what this actually means. What element? What support? fullCalendar is built around HTML DOM elements, just like any HTML application. Please describe the specific problem rather than making generalisations. Otherwise it's unclear precisely what you mean.

Comment: Hi, I achieved through event render as :                                                          eventRender: function eventRender( info ) {
   info.el.setAttribute("idgiven",info.event.id);                                                                       }                                                                                                                                                      Will add the full code here once I complete at my end.  It might help to others  who need the same requirement. Thank you @ADYSON.

Comment: No problem. Glad you solved it. It would be great if you could add it as a full answer when it is ready. I agree it could be helpful to others.